# NPE on a session filter

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to check for cookies on certain pages in a filter. My code is as follows:

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

 private ArrayList<String> urlList;

@Override
public void destroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
String url = request.getServletPath();
boolean allowedRequest = false;

if (urlList.contains(url)) {
  allowedRequest = true;
}

String username = null;
String password = null;
String loggedin = null;

if (!allowedRequest) {
  Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

  for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    String name = cookies[i].getName();
    String value = cookies[i].getValue();

    if (name.equals("bccn_username"))
      username = value;
    else if (name.equals("bccn_password"))
      password = value;
    else if (name.equals("bccn_loggedin"))
      loggedin = value;
  }

  if (loggedin.equals("true")) {
    if (username != null && password != null) {
      CheckLogin obj = new CheckLogin();
      String ret = obj.check(username, password);
      if (ret.equals("Logged In")) {

      } else {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
      }
    } else {
      response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
  } else {
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
  }

} else {
  response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}

chain.doFilter(req, resp);

}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
String urls = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");

urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
  urlList.add(token.nextToken());

}

}

}
```

And in web.xml

```
  <filter>
<filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>
    ws.abhis.SessionFilter
</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
    <param-value>index.html</param-value>
    <param-value>login.jsp</param-value>
    <param-value>styles.css</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, I am getting this error on application load:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    ws.abhis.SessionFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
```

I am a noob at this so any help is appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
 check if(cookies!=null)

Comment: If you compile your code with line number information (compiler option -g), you will easier spot the error.
My guess is that the line ´if(loggedin.equals("true")´ is giving you the exception. If this cookie is not set, then this value will be null instead of false, thus giving you the exception you are seeing.

Comment: I followed your advice and now it doesn't throw a NPE. However, its going into an infinite loop even on pages which its supposed to ignore.

Comment: You may try it out at http://abhis.ws:8080/bccn

Comment: throws an NPE for me. Try to compile the filter with -g option to have line number information. That should help you a lot.
Also try to debug the code, stepping through that filter should be revealing the issue pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

Your `urlList` variable seems to be uninitialized and doing an operation on it like this:

```
if (urlList.contains(url))
```

will cause Null Pointer Exception.

Make sure you initialize the list before using it.

Comment: I am initializing urlList in the init() method. Shouldn't that be enough. Please shed some light on the same.